# How do i convert 4 bytes of data, received using the recv method from winsock, into an int

Tags: c++, winsock, recv

Basically the server (Which is coded in python) sends a message which is made of the size of the message + the message:

```py
def sendMsg(sckt, msg: bytearray):
    msg = len(msg).to_bytes(4, "big") + msg
    sckt.sendall(msg)
```

now the client receives the first 4 bytes, but i dont know how can i convert this buffer (temp1) into the 4 byte integer

```cpp
std::vector<char> temp1(5);
int bytesreceived = recv(sckt, temp1.data(), 4, 0);
```

i will add the full client side code
socketfuncs.cpp:

```cpp
#include "socketfuncs.h"

namespace Message {
    char* Message::recvAll(SOCKET sckt,int n)
    {
        char packet[1024]; ZeroMemory(&packet, sizeof(packet));
        char data[4096]; ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(data));
        int chunk_size = 1023; if (n < chunk_size) { chunk_size = n; }
        while ((int)strlen(data) < (n-1)) {
            recv(sckt, packet, min(n - strlen(data), chunk_size), 0);
            strcat_s(data, packet);
        }
        return _strdup(data);
    }

    char* recvMsg(SOCKET sckt)
    {
        std::vector<char> temp1(5);
        int bytesreceived = recv(sckt, temp1.data(), 4, 0);
        int res = 0;
        res += temp1[0];
        res <<= 8;
        res += temp1[1];
        res <<= 8;
        res += temp1[2];
        res <<= 8;
        res += temp1[3];
        res = ntohl(res);
        std::cout << res;
        return recvAll(sckt, res);
    }

    void sendMsg(SOCKET sckt, char* command)
    {
        std::string tmpString;
        std::string tmpCommand(command);
        std::string finalString = tmpString + tmpCommand;
        const char* finalMessage = finalString.c_str();
        send(sckt, finalMessage, strlen(finalMessage), 0);
    }
}
```

socketfuncs.h:

```cpp
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#define MAX_DATA_RECEIVABLE 1000

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

namespace Message {
    char* recvAll(SOCKET sckt, int n);

    char* recvMsg(SOCKET sckt);

    void sendMsg(SOCKET sckt, char* command);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "socketfuncs.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Result = 0;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (Result) { printf("ERRORE %d", Result); return 1; }

    addrinfo* result = NULL, * ptr = NULL, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    Result = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "8081", &hints, &result);
    if (Result) { printf("ERRORE 2"); WSACleanup(); return 1; }

    SOCKET sckt = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    Result = connect(sckt, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (Result) { closesocket(sckt); sckt = INVALID_SOCKET; }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    if (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET) { printf("non e' stato possibile connettersi"); WSACleanup(); return 1; }

    char Command[256]; 
    while (1) {
        fgets(Command, 256, stdin); Command[strlen(Command)-1] = '\0';
        int sum = 0;
        Message::sendMsg(sckt, Command);
        printf("%s", Message::recvMsg(sckt));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shift and or the chars together? After converting to unsigned char.

Comment: Warning: If this is TCP/IP you need to check `bytesreceived` and loop `recv` until you get all 4 bytes. With TCP `recv` only guarantees the maximum number of bytes it will read.

Comment: in quick hack memcpy gives me an error since result isnt a void* but an int32_t

Comment: Crap. That's typo 2: `int32_t result; memcpy(&result, temp1.data(), sizeof(result)); result = ntohl(result);`

Comment: Note the frequent `strlen`ing in the `recvAll` method is unnecessary as is the bulk zerofill of the buffer. `recv` returns the number of bytes read (or 0 for disconnected or <0 for failure) ALWAYS check the return code or your program will not work. Maybe it looks like it works, but I guarantee you that there will be cases that won't. Rather than debugging these failure cases one by one as you find them, just read and make use of the return value.

Comment: Call `recv` and inspect the return code. If it's >0 add it to a running total of the number of bytes received. Terminate the string, if terminating is the right thing to do, and exit when the total is the number requested. If the code is zero, the other side hung up and you might as well exit. The caller's never getting all the data they wanted. If it's negative, see if you can recover from the error, you probably can't, and exit.

Comment: When you have a working version you should ask a question about how to improve the networking code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). I've linked to the Asking help pages so you can give them a read-over and tune the question appropriately. There is the potential for an ego-bruising, but take my word for it you'll have a robust networking library when the review's done.

Answer (score 1):

```
int res = 0;
res += temp1[0];
res <<=8;
res += temp1[1];
res <<= 8;
res+= temp1[2];
res <<= 8;
res+= temp1[3];
```

depending on the byte order you received you might need to do `ntohl` (or a similar platform specific conversion from *network byte order* to *host byte order*).

Comment: it doesnt work, even if i put in at the end res = ntohl(res)

Comment: @kreon it certainly works. I tested it just now. Please update the question to show you trying this code and show what goes wrong